# Java - How to print out what the user types as they are typing it?

Tags: java, user-interface, text, calculator, jtextfield

I am making a program where I want to create a GUI for a text calculator that I made that prints out what the user types as he or she is typing it in the text box. How can I go about this?

Comment: This would depend entirely on the specifics. What GUI library?

Comment: I am using javax.swing.* and JTextfield.

Comment: As Carcigenicate wrote, you need to be more specific. If the GUI library you are using have observers/listeners, you could use a observer to check for keyboard events and react accordingly.

Comment: SO is not a programmers-for-hire service for your homework.  Please come back when you have made an effort at this problem and have a specific question to ask.

Answer (score 1):

For javax.swing.* and JTextfield you can use the KeyAdapter class and the corresponding methods to check for user input.

You can add the key adapter to the JTextfield using the JTextfields addKeyListener method.